# Simple javascript calculator with Switch

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I need some help with a simple calculator I am doing with javascript.

The js code is as follows (my teacher want's me  to use 4 functions, for each kind of operation):

```
<script>

            function plus(a,b) {
                return (a + b);
            }

            function minus(a,b) {
                return (a - b);
            }

            function multiply(a,b) {
                return (a * b);
            }

            function divide(a,b) {
                return (a / b);
            }

            function calc() {

                var x = document.getElementById("oper1").value;
                var y = document.getElementById("operx").value;
                var z = document.getElementById("oper2").value;
                var w = document.getElementById("resul").value;

                switch (y) {
                    case '0':
                        w = plus(x, z);
                        break;

                    case '1':
                        w = minus(x, z);
                        break;

                    case '2':
                        w = multiply(x, z);
                        break;

                    case '3':
                        w = divide(x, z);
                        break;

                    default:
                        w = "Don't really know..";
                }

            }

</script>
<input type="text" id="oper1" value="">

<select id="operx">
    <option value="0">SUMAR</option>
    <option value="1">RESTAR</option>
    <option value="2">MULTIPLICAR</option>
    <option value="3">DIVIDIR</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="oper2" value="">
<input type="button" onClick="calc();" value="=">
<input type="text" id="resul" value="">
```

My code isn't working, in fact is not responding anything and I don't see any errors so I can debug... could anyone tell me if you see my mistake here? I've tried hundreds of combinations but without having an debug console or something.

Comment: Can you put a break point in your function and see if it's getting called at all?

Comment: Switch statements can be tricky. They compare values using the `===` operator, which may be replaced with an if/elsif statement to use `==` instead. Try this for example: `switch(1){ case '1': 'success'; break; default: 'fail'; }`, then this `switch(1){ case 1: 'success'; break; default: 'fail'; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not use pointers in the way you intend to use them. You have to explicitly write back your result to the output field:

```
function calc(){
  // most of your stuff
  // just replace the var w = document ... line with just
  var w;

  // your other code

  document.getElementById("resul").value = w;
}
```

Furthermore, you should parse the input values into a number using either [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). If you don't JavaScript will treat the input values as strings and then interprets `+` as string concatenation, for example.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mAEEF/)

Comment: I did both you said @Sirko and it worked perfeclty! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var w = document.getElementById("resul").value;
```

This does not allow you to set W and then have the `<input/>` update itself.  You could do one of the following instead.

After setting `w` do `document.getElementById("resul").value=w;`

OR

```
var w = document.getElementById("resul");
w.value=etc.
```

Also, bonus points if you validate your form (nice function for this case is `IsNumeric()`)

Comment: I made this into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XPSB/1/) and can verify that this works. However, check your `plus` function - it seems to simply concatenate the string values of `a` and `b`. Try passing these variables through a `parseInt` or `parseFloat` call, depending on the requirements.

Comment: you are right, I used the parseInt instead! Thanks for teh headsup!

Answer (score 0):

```
 // You can simply add button to call a function like this

 <button onclick="Calculator()">=</button>

functon Calculator(){
 var x = document.getElementById("oper1").value;
 var y = document.getElementById("operx").value;
 var z = document.getElementById("oper2").value;
           
switch(y){
case "+":
document.getElementById("resul") = x + z;
break;
case "-":
document.getElementById("resul") = x - z;
break;

case "*":
document.getElementById("resul") = x * z;
break;

case "/":
document.getElementById("resul") = x / z;
break;

case "%":
document.getElementById("resul") = x % z;
break;

Default:
alert("Choose the operator");

}
}
```